# В массиве числа, а сложение дает NaN

Tags: javascript, массивы

После сложения всех чисел из totalEquipPrices, консоль выдает NaN, хотя все объекты в массиве имеют тип Number.

Коллеги, подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело?

Спасибо

```
let equipmentCounts = [cameras.value, cableCount, 1, 1, 1, 1];
let equipmentPrices = [cameraPrice, cablePrice, powerUnitPrice, videoRecorderPrice, hddPrice, mountingKitPrice];

let equipPrices = [];

for (let i = 0; i < equipmentCounts.length; i++) { 
    let price = equipmentCounts[i] * equipmentPrices[i];
    equipPrices.push(price);
};

let totalEquipPrices;

for (let i = 0; i < equipPrices.length; i++) { 
    totalEquipPrices += equipPrices[i];
};

console.log(totalEquipPrices);
```

Comment: `totalEquipPrices == undefined`

Comment: Забыли проинициализировать `totalEquipPrices`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let totalEquipPrices = 0; сделай

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось